# Access class being referenced to?

Tags: php, oop, class

I know this may seem like a strange question, but say I have two classes;

```
class Class1 {
    private $foo;
    function addBar(Class2 &$bar)
    {
        $this->foo = $bar;
    }
}


class Class2 {
    private $foo
}

$a = new Class1;
$b = new Class2;
$a->addBar($b);
```

Is there any way `Class2` can read information from `Class1`? Even though they're in the same code block here, they are in seperate files in my script. The reason I need this is because I have `Class2` linked by reference, but `Class2` isn't allowed to be run until `Class1` has been, and I know I could pass another variable to reference `Class2` to `Class1` (eg. `$b->addFoo($a)`), but I would rather avoid that if possible.

I hope this can be done!
Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Thanks to everyone who helped, I have decided to go another way around it. Thankyou again.

Comment: Because theres code in `Class2` that I don't want to run until `Class1` has, but the only reference between them is from `Class2` to `Class1`

Comment: Then just call things in the correct order? I don't see the problem.. (add more code maybe?)

Comment: so why not add it to addBar function at the end, like `$bar->dosomethig()` Or you would like something different?

Comment: sometimes an hour of thinking can save you days of coding...

Comment: @BlackWraith You should still accept an answer. We answered in good faith, just because you changed your mind doesn't mean we should be punished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Class2` can call methods on `Class1` objects, though it can't access private data.  But it must have a reference to a `Class1` instance in order to call any methods on it.

Your example doesn't show `Class2` actually containing any code, and it sounds like you're trying to avoid calling methods on `$b`.  That doesn't make sense.  `Class2` can't "do" *anything* if you never call any methods on it.

Comment: True, but this is example code. Basically what I'm wondering, is though I can access information from `Class2` inside `Class1` via `$this->foo->foo`, but can information be shared both ways because of the `&$bar` referencing?

Comment: The fact that a `Class1` method has a reference to a `Class2` instance does not give the `Class2` instance a reference to a `Class1` instance.  At some point, somewhere, you need to call a method on `$b` and pass `$a` as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Class1 {
    private $foo;
    function addBar(Class2 $bar)
    {
        $this->foo = $bar;
        $bar->addBar($this);
    }
}

class Class2 {
    private $foo
    function addBar(Class1 $bar)
    {
        $this->foo = $bar;
    }
}

$a = new Class1;
$b = new Class2;
$a->addBar($b);
```

Comment: I removed the `&` reference because it [isn't needed](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
class Class1 {
    private $foo;
    function addBar(Class2 &$bar)
    {
        $this->foo = $bar;
        $bar->doSomething();
    }
}


class Class2 {
    private $foo
    function doSomething()
    {
        //code
    }
}

$a = new Class1;
$b = new Class2;
$a->addBar($b);
```

this way `doSomething` in `Class2()` is run after `addBar()` in `Class1`